# Limit Solr score calculation to only documents that match a filter

Tags: solr

I am trying to use a field to partition my solr documents and I need to be able to do something like first filter on this field and then do a query where the score is only calculated against the documents that pass the filter. I was trying to do this with a simple query like q=(partitionField:group1)AND(myField:something). The problem with this query is that when I load documents for say, group2, the fields in those documents then affect the scoring for group1. I need the score for searches in group1 to not be affected by documents in other groups.

It would be nice if I could use multiple cores or shards to solve this problem but unfortunately that isn't an option on my current solr host. Is there a way to do this without using multiple cores or shards?

Comment: Is filter query (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) what you are looking for? `This parameter can be used to specify a query that can be used to restrict the super set of documents that can be returned, without influencing score.`

Comment: Because the filter query doesn't influence the score it doesn't solve my problem. I am currently using a filter query but my idf scores change when I add more documents even though the added documents are excluded by the filter query. If there was a way to make the filter influence the score I think that would work for me.

Comment: Solr's default score takes idf into account. You will need to design and use a custom similarity scorer which probably ignores idf. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035831/solr-lucene-scorer. This may also help: http://solrjack.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-compile-custom-similarity-class.html