# How to load custom similarity class into Solr 4.4

Tags: java, solr, cloudera

I am trying to deploy custom similarity class into Solr 4.4 on Cloudera cluster.
Here is my code:

```
package org.apache.lucene.search.similarities;

import org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;

public class MyNewSimilarityClass extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
         return 1.0f;
    }
}
```

I found this similar question: [Solr Custom Similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428709/solr-custom-similarity), but I have additional concerns.

1. Should I compile it with errors? Or include some Solr JARs to buildpath?
2. Where should I store created JAR? Will $instanceDir/lib be ok?
3. Is Solr restart required to make Solr "see" that class?
4. What changes should I make in my schema.xml? I have already added for fieldtype:

   ```
   <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.MyNewSimilarityClass" />
   ```

   and  also changed globally for other fields:

   ```
   <similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/>
   ```

When trying to reindex my collection, I am receiving following error:

```
Error: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml]   
       fieldType "text_wiki": Error loading class 
      'org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.MyNewSimilarityClass'
```

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035831/solr-lucene-scorer