# How can I add new methods to Lucene/Solr similarity class?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I've written a new class, called `MyNewSimilarityClass`, that extends the  `DefaultSimilarity` class in Solr; in particular, I've defined a custom method in that class, because the existing ones are not sufficient for my needs, and I want to improve the ranking algorithm.

To make sure that my new class gets used by Solr, I've added the following line in the `schema.xml`:

```
<similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.MyNewSimilarityClass"/>
```

I know that my class is added to the classloader, and that Solr actually uses it: when I run a Solr query, the methods I've overridden and modified are working.

However, my custom method is currently not used by Solr when I run a query. Although I've defined that new method in my class and my class gets loaded as expected, I do not know where I should call my custom method so that it be used in the ranking algorithm.

I know how to override methods when extending classes in Lucene/Solr, I don't know how to add in new/custom methods.

**Which file, in Solr, do I need to modify so that a query use my custom method?**

Comment: You should seriously learn some Java before trying to hack Solr. After you learn Java, this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035831/solr-lucene-scorer

Comment: Also, this is the fourth time you've posted this question, and you're still posting the exact same background material without expanding it with what you've tried or where things are going wrong.

Comment: @MatsLindh I apologise; I'm facing a related but different problem this time. I've edited and improved my question as best I could. Hopefully, it will make more sense now. Let me know if it's still missing relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query won't use your custom method unless you modify the inner workings of Lucene. There's an interface that the scoring mechanism uses, and which is what you implement in your code. This is what you have to work with, unless you want to create a custom build of Lucene and possibly Solr - something I would not recommend unless you're fairly experience both with Lucene and Java and want to maintain a custom version for yourself.

I'm not really sure why you'd need a custom method to be called, though. The interface allows for both additive and multiplied scoring being applied. When you create a custom similarity class you usually use the [DefaultSimilarity class](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html) as the starting point, and then override the different parts that you want to score differently. There is nothing stopping you from invoking one of your custom methods as part of that scoring method, or if the score returned from the parent method is within a certain range.

See [Lucene's Practical Scoring Formula](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) for where each part of the DefaultSimilarity class is hooked in (or have a look at the TFIDF Similarity class to get alternative implementations).

If you have more specific questions about how to use either of these classes, please ask a suitable question with what you've tried and which problems you're experiencing.