# how to get resultcounts for each word if multiword-search was without results

Tags: solr

On our webshop I want to implement a feature which should do the following:

If a user e.g. searches for "phone magnum", there will be no results.

If there were no results I want to give him the possibility to see

- that search for "phone" will give him 139 results
- and search for "magnum" will get 12 results.

I don't want to start several queries only for getting those counts. But at the moment I have no Idea how to do that.

I read the Solr-wiki for faceting, but didn't find anything useful for my problem. Maybe I missed something ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to avoid multiple queries. If your first search on the phrase `"phone magnum"` does not return any results, you could issue one query per search keyword with `rows=0` which will give you only the counts. This should be efficient, since you are not building any result documents and only getting the result counts.

However, if you **really** want to avoid the subsequent queries, here is one apporach: Have a field in your index which does not take IDF into account. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226761/1333610) on how to do that.) Once that field is available (call it say `name_no_idf`) issue a query against this field `name_no_idf:(phone magnum)`. Notice that this is not a phrase search.

The documents which contain both `phone` and `magnum` in the `name_no_idf` field will get a score of 2, while the docs matching only one word will get a score of 1. To this query you add `facet=true&facet.field=name`. Then the facet counts you get for these two words will be the counts you are looking for. But few warnings:

1. if one of the words is very infrequent, you may need to increase `facet.limit`
2. facet queries are expensive