# How to enforce stable result scores in SOLR? By defining fixed docFreq?

Tags: solr, lucene, tf-idf

We have the following use case, which requires us to keep the result scores in SOLR stable:

- Start with a core of 10 million documents.
- Some queries are run against this core. I know that the scores have no absolute meaning, but we have a way to define a cut off value for each particular query. It might be 3.14 or 0.00001, but we just take the docs having a higher score. This works fine so far.
- Now we add a few 100k documents more to the core.
- We run the same queries again. Due to the changes in the docFreq, we get minimal changed result scores. So the scoring of some "old" docs can move above or below the saved threshold. That is, what we want to get rid off.

We evaluated several options, but without success. The idea is to override the doc frequencies with fixed values. That's not possible with a custom Similarity implementation, because it is too "late" in the process. The retrieval of the docFreq is coupled to the IndexReader and I did not saw a way to override something. The last option might be to hack into the distribute idf cache, i.e. having a custom implementation of https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/stats/package-tree.html . I did not yet figured out how to do that and how/where the cache interacts with the query.

But the main purpose is, to keep the results scores stable, even when adding new documents. Any hint would be very appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, therefore as comment: Solr supprts [a wider set of similarities](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/similarities/package-summary.html). You can [define and configure the similarity globally in the schema.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Schema+Elements). Probably one of them offers what you need or is configurable to that point.

Comment: At least to me knowledge, this does not work. What we want is some predefined term->docFreq mapping which would be used as lookup, instead of the real values. But if you reach the similarity code, this lookup has already been done.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16226761/2160152) of @Arun shows how to get rid of the IDF using a custom similarity.