# Solr 5.5.0 error when overriding ClassicSimilarityFactory

Tags: search, solr

Context:: Getting error in solr-core 5.5.0 when overriding ClassicSimilarityFactory. Have pasted the logs and class. Overriding ClassicSimilarityFactory throws error- Context:: Getting error in solr-core 5.5.0 when overriding ClassicSimilarityFactory. Have pasted the logs and class. Overriding ClassicSimilarityFactory throws error-

```
package com.Others;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarityFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PayloadSimilarityFactory extends ClassicSimilarityFactory {
  @Override
  public void init(SolrParams params) {
    super.init(params);
  }

  @Override
  public Similarity getSimilarity() {
    return new PayloadSimilarity();
  }
}

class PayloadSimilarity extends ClassicSimilarity  {
  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PayloadSimilarity.class);
  //Here's where we actually decode the payload and return it.
  @Override
  public float scorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) {

    logger.info("PayloadSimilarity ---- " + payload);
    if (payload == null)
      return 1.0F;

    return PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, payload.offset);
  }
}



Schema.xml file :

    <fieldType name="payloads" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="true">
        <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float" delimiter="|"/>
        </analyzer>
        <similarity class="com.Others.PayloadSimilarityFactory"/>
    </fieldType>

   </types>

Error Logs :

 Error creating core [catalog]: Could not load conf for core catalog: Can't load schema /Users/z002cww/repo/jarvis-solr-config/config/catalog/conf/schema.xml: FieldType 'payloads' is configured with a similarity, but the global similarity does not support it: class org.apache.solr.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarityFactory
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core catalog: Can't load schema /Users/z002cww/repo/jarvis-solr-config/config/catalog/conf/schema.xml: FieldType 'payloads' is configured with a similarity, but the global similarity does not support it: class org.apache.solr.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarityFactory
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:812)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.access$000(CoreContainer.java:87)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:467)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Plz visit this site to know how to ask a good question so that we can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Found Solution - Add <similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/> below first line (schema name ="XYZ" ) in schema.xml & it will work. Let me know if anyone is facing some issue

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `SchemaSimilarityFactory` as the configured default similarity to support using per field similarities.

```
<similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/>
```

See one of the answers to [Solr Lucene Scorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226761/137650) and [the mailinglist answer for the same question](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201212.mbox/%3Czarafa.50cf9a12.4840.73b80db90203a3be@mail.openindex.io%3E).

Comment: Can u tell me where this line - <similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/> has to be added in my schema.xml file as I am still getting above error after placing <similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/> in schema.xml file.

Comment: Be sure that you don't have a different element there, and that you have reloaded your collection. You can see how SchemaSimilarityFactory can be configured in the reference guide: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Schema+Elements

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Schema+Elements